# Can I have a non-virtual abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, abstract

Abstract classes are made with a virtual function and then "= 0", but I was wondering if I can make a non-virtual abstract class. I have a class that I don't want to be instantiated, but I don't want it to be virtual. When I try I get the message "pure specifier = 0 only allowed on virtual functions".

Comment: Protected constructors?

Comment: @PasserBy Ah yes, that's a good solution. Seeing as you're passing by, do you know if I can do "using namespace" so that it's only visible inside a class? Or do I have to do it in each class function?